# C-style 2D-dynamic array with need to perform only one free() operation

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I want to build 2D-array without need to perform many free() operations.

```
#include <iostream>
#define un unsigned
#define ln long

un ln ** array_builder(un ln rows, un ln cols)
{
    register const un ln row_memory = cols * sizeof(un ln);
    auto array = (un ln **) malloc( rows * ( sizeof(un ln *) + row_memory ) );

// First line: The bytes of memory required to store a single row in the array
// Second line: We want to store all the pointers in the single array

    auto pointer = (void *) array[0];  // sizeof(void *) == 1. It is convenient for our purposes
    pointer += rows * sizeof(un ln *);  /* Thus we skip the first pointers in the array (their amount equals 'rows').
                                       This space is considered to store pointers of array[row] type */

    for (un ln int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (un ln *) pointer;  // We write pointers to each row in the array[row]
        pointer += row_memory;
    }

    return array;
// We've built 2D-array. Now we can access to the elements of this array by convenient way as array[row][col]
// Don't forget to free(array) after use
}
```

But this program works incorrect. For example, when I try to change some value by array[row][col]=some_value it makes program crash in different places every time.

Comment: It looks to me like you are working with C. Would you allow a c++ solution? Otherwise I would remove the c++ tag.

Comment: that's a very weird data structure. Why not creating a 1D array and compute the row indexes by multiplying by row size?

Comment: `#define un unsigned`, `#define ln long` ... why?

Comment: ... lazy typist? Search/replace after you finish the code.

Comment: Or, really do yourself a favor and don't manually implement matrices. There are many open source matrix libraries out there with both C and C++ APIs and you simply won't beat them for efficiency.

Comment: Yes, of course, it's weird. But I try to make it works as a challenge for beginner and I don't know how.

Comment: @systemcpro maybe he learns C. Then he follows the correct path. Not the arduino one "it is not worth learning as you can get a good library"

Comment: Yes I see your point but writing matrices and matrix operations is a non-trivial task. Maybe something easier - I think my heart would sink if I was asked tomorrow to implement one. I think I'd just quit :)

Comment: I must be getting old.  I just can't read this code at all, even though I know "un ln" means "unsigned long".  @AndrewSonin : cute experiment, but my advice is that you write it off as a filed one.

Comment: Comment in code `sizeof(void *) == 1` is likely wrong.  I'd expect `sizeof(void) == 1`.  Further, even if true, pointer math of `void *` type is undefined in C,  Unsure about C++.  Suggest using `unsigned char *pointer = ...`.

Comment: This is not a C question. Generally speaking, in very few cases can a question have both C and C++ tags. This isn't such a rare case.

Comment: @AndrewSonin you missed `#define in int` and then you could have the even more unreadable `for (un ln in i = 0; i < rows; i++)`

Comment: @KubaOber OP's goal is to write C++ in "C-style 2D-dynamic array".  It certainly makes sense to tag a post dual language when the goal is to match styles/idioms of one code in another as one is able.  OTOH, if such a goal makes for a good post is a separate issue.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, one does not use malloc and free nor the equivalent new and delete. One would use proper RAII, that is, no manual freeing resources.
For a 2 dimensional array, one would use a single field like this:

```
std::vector<int> data;
data.resize(width * height);

//in case you know the amount of data at compile time use a static sized field
std::array<int, width * heigth> data;

//access a single cell
int cell = data[y * width + x];

//or obtain a pointer to a row of cells
int *rowptr = &data[y * width];
int cellinrow = rowptr[x];
```

This is both more space and time efficient than allocating multiple rows.

In C you would equivalently allocate a single block of ints with malloc or use a static sized int[width * height] array;

Note that you should never mix C and C++ nor use the register keyword nor lazy #defines

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.  The compiler needs to know what type to return and this requires the size of the internal array.  Plus you can't return arrays anyway.

What you could do is make a class that does it for you.  You could call it say, `vector`, or something.  Make it responsible for allocating and deallocating a dynamic array of some type...then put one inside of another like so:

```
vector<vector<unsigned long>> {rows, vector<unsigned long>{cols,0}};
```

You might be able to find someone has already written something like this if you peruse the Internet for C++ tutorials and references.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm for a fake 2D array `unsigned long **` - which is a pointer to a pointer to `unsigned long`

The allocation needs to

1) enough memory for the array of pointers  `array`.
2) maybe some padding for alignment of `unsigned long`
3) `rows*cols` memory of `unsigned long`

This can all be done with 1 allocation and so only 1 `free()` is needed.

Assign the `array` elements to point to the 3rd part of the allocation.   Keep in mind alignment requirements.

**Unclear why C++ code would want this.**

---

OP's approach is similar, yet lacks the alignment considerations.  This can crash code if a pointer is narrower than `unsigned long` or under other circumstances.

--

Some untested C++ like code in the manner of "C-style" using `malloc()`.

```
typedef unsigned long data_t;

data_t **alloc_2Ddata(size_t rows, size_t cols) {
  data_t **a;
  size_t row_ptrs_size = sizeof *a * rows;
  size_t data_size = sizeof **a * rows * cols;
  size_t pad = (sizeof **a - row_ptrs_size % sizeof **a) % sizeof **a;
  a = (data_t **) malloc(row_ptrs_size + pad + data_size);
  if (a) {
    data_t *data = (data_t*) (((char*) a) + row_ptrs_size + pad);
    for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
      a[r] = data;
      data += cols;
    }
  }
  return a;
}
```