# How to create a large Eigen matrix from a 9222*9222 2d array in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, matrix, eigen

I have tried mapping the matrix from the array using

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, 9222, 9222, Eigen::RowMajor>> m(&A[0][0]);
```

where A is double **A.

```
A = (double **)malloc((fullsize)*sizeof(double *));         //allocate memory dynamically for matrix A
    for (i = 0; i < fullsize; i++)
        A[i] = (double *)malloc((2 * fullsize)*sizeof(double));
```

but the program crashes.

I have tried

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, 9222, 9222, Eigen::RowMajor>> m(&A[0][0]);
```

but the program won't compile.

Comment: And fullsize is?

Comment: @Surt its 9222.

Comment: As far as I can see Map expects a contiguous array, so use double A[fullsize*fullsize]; and give Map &A[0].

Comment: I tried:`std::vector<double> data;
 data.resize(fullsize * fullsize);

 {
  for (int n = 0; n<fullsize; n++)
  for (int m = 0; m<fullsize; m++)
  {
   data[n*fullsize + m] = A[n][m];
  }
 }
 Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, fullsize, fullsize,Eigen::RowMajor>> m(&data[0]);` and it still doesn't work @Srut

Comment: Adding to the existing answers: You shouldn't use fixed-sized Matrices for very large sizes. Try `Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> > m(&A[0], 9222, 9222);` instead.

Answer (score 1):

A is a pointer pointing to a contiguous field of pointers. These pointers point to a contiguous field of doubles. Thus A doesn't point to a contiguous field of doubles. &A[0] points to the first pointer, &A[0][0] points to the first element in the field of doubles pointed to by &A[0].

Don't use malloc in C++. Have look at this to create a contigous 2D field of doubles: [C-style 2D-dynamic array with need to perform only one free() operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446797/c-style-2d-dynamic-array-with-need-to-perform-only-one-free-operation/45446979#45446979)

Comment: I tried:std::vector<double> data; data.resize(fullsize * fullsize); { for (int n = 0; n<fullsize; n++) for (int m = 0; m<fullsize; m++) { data[n*fullsize + m] = A[n][m]; } } Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, fullsize, fullsize,Eigen::RowMajor>> m(&data[0]); and it still doesn't work @Techel

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Map reinterpret the array as a matrix.

```
double A[fullsize*fullsize];

Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, 9222, 9222, Eigen::RowMajor>> m(&A[0]);
```

The vector version might work, but you give Map the address of the vector and not the data in it.

Comment: this only works for small data, not for 9222*9222 @Surt

Comment: @Sanju, I wonder what your compiler says as the array is only 680MB large.

Comment: `Unhandled exception at 0x010320F7 in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x00802000).

The program '[55352] ConsoleApplication1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)`

Comment: Ok, so you need to new the A.